# JSON Schema references with $ref

Tags: json, jsonschema, ref, swagger-codegen, jsonschema2pojo

I have multiple schema definitions in multiple files (multiple .json files),

Does JSON schema allow schema definition in multiple .json files in multiple directories ?
Or should all schema definitions (all *.json files) reside in one directory ?

Couldnt get much info from http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html.

The reason i am asking is while generating POJO's from .json files in Java app, jsonschema2pojo plugin is able to handle multiple directories whereas swagger code-gen plugin can only handle one directory. I would like to know if its JSON-Schema guideline or plugin deficiency.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4634) seems to ask a similar question

Comment: Plugin deficiency. It's totally valid, and even recommended, to split up your schemas into multiple files in any number of folders which make sense. Sadly, support for resolving references is lacking.